"Android emulator showing nothing except black screen" solved with wipe user data?
I had a problem Android emulator showing nothing except black screen . I searched it and found answer here on this site.
One of the answers matched with me (I am using Ubuntu 22.04 , android studio Iguana 2023.2.1 , SDK 34 UpsideDownCake.
The matter is I am learning RN development via Expo. SO when I did this,I also got rid of Expo Go application on emulator (Pixel 4G) .
So, I had to reinit the app after npm run. I mean, it starts the app all over restoring all data to initial.
Is wiping the user data really solution to the problem? As I think it just removes the part containing problem, not solving the problem itself.
From terminal it was seen:
I was facing problem with ColorBuffer when I had all black screen:
E0420 00:33:53.267816 7831 FrameBuffer.cpp:3761] Failed to find ColorBuffer:0  E0420 00:33:53.307921 7831 FrameBuffer.cpp:3761] Failed to find ColorBuffer:0
I tried rebooting the device, thinking maybe it is another Linux thing.
I switched off and on the emulator multiple times.

This may be related to the issue asked here which found a work-around by using a lower Android API Verion (i.e. use API 31 on your Android Virtual Device).

In my case it worked on Android API 33
